# How do I round corners of web part titles?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, style-library, style.css

How do I round the corners of my web part titles on my SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.js-webpart-titleCell {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: How do I add it to the existing style?<style type="text/css">
.ms-WPBorder {
 BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #666666
}
.ms-partline {
 BACKGROUND: #ff9900
}
.ms-WPTitle {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPTitle A {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPTitle A:visited {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPHeader {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #666666
}</style><script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I am new to this sorry.  It isn't changing.  Do I need to edit the css file add another content editor webpart?  This is what I have<style type="text/css">
.ms-WPTitle Cell {
 BORDER-RADIUS: 8px 8px 0px 0px
}
.ms-WPBorder {
 BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #666666; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #666666
}
.ms-partline {
 BACKGROUND: #ff9900
}
.ms-WPTitle {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPTitle A {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPTitle A:visited {
 COLOR: #ffffff
}
.ms-WPHeader {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #666666
}</style><script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: No proplem, take your time, just tell me your sharepoint version ?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: great, let's continue now, forget your style , just add script editor web part and add <style>.js-webpart-titleCell {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}</style> if it's working propely and you need to apply it for all site you should include it in your css file. by adding only this .js-webpart-titleCell {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
} after <style type="text/css">

Comment: ``.js-webpart-titleCell`` is not an OOTB one. So if it is applied async later it will overrule the one declared in the Script-Editor-WebPart. use higher CSS Specificity: ``.js-webpart-titleCell.js-webpart-titleCell`` to have your style definition applied.